# Fingerstyle finger economy - how to play phrases that require index finger on high strings?

Tags: technique, fingering, fingerstyle-guitar

Is this fingering correct/optimal?

```
    1    4
    4   4
    3  4
      2

E|--5-------
B|--7----7--
G|--7---7---
D|-----7----
A|----------
E|----7-----
```

Answer (score 5):

Different styles fit different people, so correct or optimal has many answers. I would have used:

```
2*    4
4    3
3   2
   1

* or 1 if strings are inadvertently muted
```

(I'm assuming we're talking left hand fingers here, fingerstyle guitar usually means the that the right hand fingers are used to strum.)

Comment: I have to agree here - in playing the guitar there is rarely a 'correct' fingering, unless you want to match exactly how the original artist played. Use whatever works best for you.